# How is user.dir System Property interpreted under commons-daemon procrun & log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, daemon, apache-commons, procrun

I have installed a java batch process using the version of procrun that ships with tomcat 5.5.33:

```
   Commons Daemon Service Runner version 1.0.5.0/Win32 (Jan  5 2011) 
   Copyright (c) 2000-2011 The Apache Software Foundation.
```

In the installation, I specify (among other JVM options):

```
  --JvmOptions="-Duser.dir=C:\LOCAL\serverapps"
```

My log4j.properties configuration includes:

```
   log4j.appender.InfoLogFile.File=../logs/info.log
```

However, the info.log file is being written to:

```
   C:\WINDOWS\logs
```

I've checked the value of `user.dir` at many different points and it's always `C:\LOCAL\serverapps`.

But, log4j is behaving as if `user.dir=C:\Windows\System32` (or some other subir of `C:\Windows`).

From what I can tell from the log4j source (1.2.16), the `FileAppender` deals only with the `java.io.FileOutputStream` and File classes which claim to make paths relative from the `user.dir` location.

I've worked around the issue, but I am curious: has anyone else has encountered this type of behaviour?  If so, what's really going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileAppender, when given a relative path, creates a file withing the current working directory - not the user home directory.

You need to pass the ${user.dir} within the filename.

SRC:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.java?view=markup

*EDIT: see comment below for correction - user.dir != user.home*

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4117557

Comment: `user.home` = User's home directory
`user.dir`  = User's current working directory

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that.
I just found this: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4117557
It seems Oracle (...) is aware of some bugs, as it seems that user.dir is not always respected. Looks like you're better of using a non-standard system property (as you write in your comment below).

Comment: PhilW, your comment has the correct reason for the failure (the Sun/Oracle bug), but your original answer is a bit misleading.  You should not have to pass the `${user.dir}` as a prefix to the filename because `FileAppender` simply hands off to `FileInputStream` and that process should respect `user.dir`, but does not.  If you can update your original answer to point directly to the bug, I'll remove my accepted answer and accept yours, since you correctly brought forward the Java bug - which is the explanation I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `${user.dir}` in the `lo4j.properties` and it has worked. Have you tried?

```
log4j.appender.InfoLogFile.File=${user.dir}/logs/info.log
```

Comment: I had worked around with a very similar idea.  Added a new property `${logging.base}` and put it in the `log4j.properties` file.  To test your idea, I used `${user.dir}` and it places the files in the correct directory (i.e. not under `C:\WINDOWS`).   However ... that still doesn't answer the question.  In fact, it adds more intrigue.  What's actually going on that make relative paths NOT interpreted relative to `${user.dir}`?

Answer (score 0):

PhilW's comment points to the correct answer to the original question.  That is, Oracle/Sun declares an issue https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4117557 when `user.dir` is set via the command line.  That is the reason why the relative path is not properly understood when logging files are written out.

By using a an absolute path (even prefixing with `${user.dir}` -- which can be trusted at that point - even if the JVM gets the value wrong internally) as Phil, Amir and I all suggest, you avoid the issue altogether.